# Hebrew appears as gibberish, DB importing with PyPyODBC

Tags: python, python-2.7, hebrew, pypyodbc

I'm trying to work with a Hebrew database, unfortunately the output is gibberish. What am I doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pypyodbc 
conn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\client.mdb')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Client''')
d = cur.fetchone()
for field in d:
    print field
```

If I look at cur.fetchone():

```
'\xf0\xf1\xe0\xf8', '\xe0\xe9\xe0\xe3'
```

Output:

```
αΘαπ
2001
εδßΘ
αΘ°σ
```

Comment: I'm not too sure about Unicode encodings, but it looks like it might have encoded it in something other that UTF-8 or that there's some kind of offset between fields and unicode strings. `\xf0` is the start of a 4-byte UTF-8 string, but Hebrew characters should all be 2-byte and have a binary representation starting with `1100xxxx`.

Comment: Might it be in [Windows 1255 encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305148)?

Answer (score 2):

If either of נסאר or איאד is meaningful, then try:

`field.decode('cp1255')`

Google Translate suggests this might correspond to a person named Iyad Nassar.

Comment: it does. I really don't understand why it works on your machine, but on mine I get "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position..."

Comment: I'm using PyCharm IDE to represent things for me, with `# coding: utf-8` at the top, like you.

It's definitely encoded in the Windows 1255 encoding then. It's a bit of a pain, but each hex number corresponds to a single Hebrew character or vowel mark. I also have Hebrew installed as a language on Windows so that I could help my partner with a Hebrew language corpus study.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Answer (score 0):

try use:

```
field.encode('utf-8')
```